# Panel ArrangeOverride & MeasureOverride Methods

Tags: c#, wpf, panel

Can someone provide a simple example for this functions?
What i`m trying to realize is something like this:

When i have 1 child - i want to be displayed on full screen;

When i have 2 children - i want to have the same height and width and be displayed each one on a full row;

When i have 3 children, something like this:

```
|*************|
|   1  |   2  |
|*************|
|      3      |
|*************|
```

And when i have 4 children to be:

```
|*************|
|   1  |   2  |
|*************|
|   3  |   4  |
|*************|
```

How can i achieve this?

Regards.

EDIT 1: I think this panel can inherit the UniformGrid somwhow.

Comment: The title is not good for your question.Maybe `Custom a smart layout panel  by children's count` is a good choice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that you don't need to override `MeasureOverride` because your panel will take all available space, so you just need to implement your placing logic in `ArrangeOverride` something like this:

```
public class CustomPanel : Panel
{
    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        if (Children.Count == 1)
        {
            Children[0].Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), finalSize));
        }
        else if (Children.Count == 2)
        {
            var halfFinalSize = new Size(finalSize.Width, finalSize.Height/2);
            Children[0].Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), halfFinalSize));
            Children[1].Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0, finalSize.Height / 2), halfFinalSize));
        }
        else if (Children.Count == 3)
        {
            var halfFinalSize = new Size(finalSize.Width, finalSize.Height / 2);
            var quarterSize = new Size(finalSize.Width / 2, finalSize.Height / 2);

            Children[0].Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), halfFinalSize));
            Children[1].Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0, finalSize.Height / 2), quarterSize));
            Children[2].Arrange(new Rect(new Point(finalSize.Width / 2, finalSize.Height / 2), quarterSize));
        }
        else if (Children.Count == 4)
        {
            var quarterSize = new Size(finalSize.Width / 2, finalSize.Height / 2);
            Children[0].Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), quarterSize));
            Children[1].Arrange(new Rect(new Point(finalSize.Width / 2, 0), quarterSize));
            Children[2].Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0, finalSize.Height / 2), quarterSize));
            Children[3].Arrange(new Rect(new Point(finalSize.Width / 2, finalSize.Height / 2), quarterSize));
        }
        else if (Children.Count > 4)
        {
            //???
        }

        return base.ArrangeOverride(finalSize);
    }
}`
```

PS: make sure that Children count is less than 5

Comment: Looks like the right technical outline but you'd want a more algorithmic solution for the layout. Up to 99+ children.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, Rock3rRullz asked for up to 4 elements :-) i.e. photos in a tile (windows phone like) 4 items is a limit + I am a bit lazy :( and author didn't specify cases like 5 elements.

Comment: Hy. Yes i will always have 4 elements top. Thank you this saved me a lot of time.

Comment: @Nagg: FinalSize is never infinite in ArrangeOverride(), as opposed to availableSize in "MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)", which indeed can be infinite.

Comment: @PeterHuber, agree, it won't allow you to pass infinity in MeasureOverride as a return value. I'll remove it from my answer

Comment: @Nagg: Just to clarify: The size received in ArrangeOverride might not be the size returned by MeasureOverride. Even the size passed in Arrange is not necessarily the same as received in ArrangeOverride. FrameworkElement.Arrange applies all kinds of changes before passing the size on.